# Coloring if() condition in exel

Tags: fonts, microsoft-excel-2016, text-formatting

Hello to the comunity,

In a cell of an excel file, let's say that I want to enter the following formula

if(a1>a2,"test1","test2")

What I want to achieve is that the font of both test1 and test2 to be in different colors.

One way is by using conditional formatting and apply different rules. However, I wonder if there is an alternative -more direct- approach, by specifying font coloring directly inside of `if()` formula or by using `VBA`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using VBA. I assume your formula is in Cell B1

In your Excel worksheet, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to access the VBA Editor.

Select your sheet in the left pane. In the right side code window, select **Worksheet** from the drop down and then select **Change** event from the subsequent drop down.

Following placeholder for the subroutine shall be available therein.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Place the following code in the same.

```
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Or Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
  If Range("B1").Formula = "=IF(A1>A2,""test1"",""test2"")" Then

        If Range("A1").Value > Range("A2").Value Then
            Range("B1").Font.Color = vbRed
        Else
            Range("B1").Font.Color = vbGreen
        End If

  End If
End If
```

In above example I have used standard vbRed and vbGreen. Select as per your choice.

[image]